# useEffect fails on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, api, use-effect

I am an infant programmer and I am trying to fetch an api and style the results using React. My page works fine on the initial load and subsequent saves on VScode,but when I actually refresh the page from the browser I get the error thats posted on image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej8NK.png):

**Here is my code:** App.js

````
```import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import Students from './components/Students';
import styled from 'styled-components';

function App() {
  const [studentInfo, setStudentInfo] = useState({});
  const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState({});
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    getStudents();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    getStudents();
    console.log('useEffect');
  }, [searchTerm]);
  const getStudents = async () => {
    const url = 'https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students';
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        searchTerm != ''
          ? setStudentInfo(filterStudents(data.students))
          : setStudentInfo(data.students);
      });
  };

    const filterStudents = (studentsArray) => {
    return studentsArray.filter((info) => {
      return (
        info.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
        info.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
      );
    });
  };
  console.log(searchTerm);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Students
        studentInfo={studentInfo}
        setSearchTerm={setSearchTerm}
        searchTerm={searchTerm}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;```
````

**here is my component Students.js:**

````
```import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import GradeDetails from './GradeDetails';

const Students = ({ studentInfo, searchTerm, setSearchTerm }) => {
  console.log(typeof studentInfo);
  console.log(studentInfo[0]);
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(false);

  const handleDetails = () => {
    setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed);
  };
  const average = (arr) => {
    let sum = 0;
    arr.map((num) => {
      sum = sum + parseInt(num);
    });
    return sum / arr.length.toFixed(3);
  };
  console.log(isCollapsed);
  return (
    <Container>
      <Input
        type="text"
        value={searchTerm}
        placeholder="Search by name"
        onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value.toLowerCase())}
      />
      {studentInfo?.map((student) => (
        <Wrapper key={student.id}>
          <ImageContainer>
            <Image src={student.pic}></Image>
          </ImageContainer>
          <ContentContainer>
            <Name>
              {student.firstName} {student.lastName}{' '}
            </Name>
            <Email>Email: {student.email}</Email>
            <Company>Company: {student.company}</Company>
            <Skills>Skill: {student.skill}</Skills>

            <Average>Average:{average(student.grades)}%</Average>
          </ContentContainer>
          <ButtonContainer>
            <Button onClick={handleDetails}>+</Button>
          </ButtonContainer>
          {isCollapsed && <GradeDetails studentInfo={studentInfo} />}
        </Wrapper>
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};```
````

Every time I have the error, I comment out the codes in Students.js starting from studentInfo.map until the  and save and then uncomment it and save and everything works fine again.

I am hoping someone can help me make this work every time so that I don't have to sit at the edge of my seat all the time. Thank you and I apologize for the long question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an empty *object* as the initial state for `studentInfo` (the value passed to `useState` hook will be used as the default value - [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)):

```
const [studentInfo, setStudentInfo] = useState({});
```

`.map` is only supported on *Arrays*. So this is failing when the component is rendering before the `useEffect` has completed and updated the value of `studentInfo` from an object, to an array. Try swapping your initial state to be an array instead:

```
const [studentInfo, setStudentInfo] = useState([]);
```